# How can I create a "zoom" effect using jQuery and switching the source image?

Tags: jquery, zooming

I have an array of images that get on the browser and when the user hovers over them I have this effect occur:

```
 $('.thisImage').hover(function(){
            zindexnr++;// Bring picture to the foreground
            var cssObj = { 
                'z-index' : zindexnr,
                '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(0deg)',
                '-webkit-box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px'
            };
            $(this).css(cssObj);
        }, function(event, ui){
            var tempVal = Math.round(Math.random());
            if(tempVal == 1) {
                var rotDegrees = randomXToY(330, 360); // rotate left
            }else{
                var rotDegrees = randomXToY(0, 30); // rotate right
            }
            var cssObj = { 
                '-webkit-box-shadow' : '',
                '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotDegrees +'deg)',
            };
            $(this).css(cssObj);
        });
```

The images rotate pretty nicely and have a good drop shadow. But what I want to do is to change the source of the image from a thumb-sized one to a big one and make it seem as if the image were zooming (as much as possible). How can I make the latter?

Also, would it be a good idea to preload the big images as well?

**EDIT**

I should say I already looked around some posts in SO but didn't find any that quite did what I want to. Hence I'm asking.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WatTA/ so you guys can see what I've got so far =)

Comment: Would you have a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live demo with which we could experiment?

Comment: As for preloading the big images it depends on how many images are there and what are their resolutions. Loading big images beforehand is n't the best idea, on the other hand however, loading on demand would probably result in some "flickering", since the bigger version of hovered image would take some time to load.

Comment: @David Here's the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WatTA/ got random images from the internet because I'm working in a local host sorry about the long links for those

Comment: @Luis, no worries about the long names/links. Thanks for the demo =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing around with your images width. By setting the image width on hover, the height will change and keep in proportion. **This will create the zoom effect** [this version is without animation]

http://jsfiddle.net/WatTA/1/

You will see that I set the `origW` variable at the top to make it global, so that on mouse out you can revert back to original width state.

**UPDATE**

I have added the image source switcher:

http://jsfiddle.net/WatTA/2/

I have added another array, it matches the array `images` and `imagesHover` to swap source on hover.

Hope this helps.